# Scope svelte component styles even when global operator is used

Tags: css, svelte

I have created generic svelte components which I want to add to an existing project. The components make use of third party libraries which use `global` operator for some of the styles.
When I add the component to the existing project, the styles of the existing project are affected by the child component.

Example:
[image: nested components with no global style]

In the image above, there is an outer element with `* { color: green }` and an inner element with `* { color: red }`. It works as expected, no style is leaked inside or outside.

However, if I use `:global()`, that style is applied to parent components as well. I'm using UI libraries that do this, so I have no control over their use of `global`. For example, if I add a material button using a library, the parent styles go haywire:
[image: nested components with child element using global style]

I used a simple example which could actually be solved by redefining a few css styles on the parent component, but I have many components with many layers of nesting using multiple third party components which attempt to change a lot of global styles so redifining styles in parent would be impractical.
Is there a way to tell svelte to scope all of a components styles to itself?

ps: In the example images above, the child element is converted to web-component. So the `global` styles are leaking out not only in svelte apps, but even leaking outside the shadow dom

Comment: you can to render render your svelte component in a shadow dom, as a web component.

Comment: @CD global styles leak out of shadow dom too. The example in the question is using a web component